# Where are the C++ compiler folders LIB and INCLUDE located?

Tags: c, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, datastage

I'm trying to set C++ compiler for IBM DataStage ETL tool. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable (x64) for my Windows Server 2008 R2. The DataStage guide says that

> Visual Studio .NET 2008 Express Edition C++:
>
> Set the LIB environment variable to the location of the library
>   directory for the SDK. For example, for Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
>   2008 Express Edition C++, a typical location is C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib.
>
> Set the INCLUDE environment variable to the location of the include
>   directory for the SDK. For example, for Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
>   2008 Express Edition C++, a typical location is C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include.

I can find the Lib folder from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\

but not the Include folder. Where it is located? There is also these kind of folders under

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0

What are the right folders for LIB and INCLUDE Environmental variables?

Comment: I have the 2010 version and I've found those folders: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib (and the same for Include).

Comment: You installed the wrong thing.  Do you even have a compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a link installed on your start menu to run a visual studio command prompt (probably under the visual studio express folder in the menu). If you run that it should set up a command prompt window with those already set correctly.

So you can either use that or at least look what they should be set to.