# Not able to install python-libmemcached on windows

Tags: python, pip, memcached, pylibmc

I have been trying to install pylibmc package in window's environment but for that it requires python-libmemcached package to be install. So i tried installing the same but giving error:

```
Collecting python-libmemcached
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/b6/30af3c760790e7ca7cd0210a2d6ed76a2ce6602dd53b1a8b7365f33d0eba/python-libmemcached-0.40dev.tar.gz

Building wheels for collected packages: python-libmemcached
Building wheel for python-libmemcached (setup.py) ... error
Complete output from command "d:\tfs\ml apps\recommendation engine 
main\source_code\environment\scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:
\\Users\\ABHISH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u3p5o7l2\\python- 
libmemcached\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n
', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d 
C:\Users\ABHISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_tcqfa2b --python-tag cp37:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.7
copying cmemcached.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
running build_ext
building 'cmemcached_imp' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.7
creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c         
/nologo 
/Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Id:\tfs\ml apps\recommendation engine 
main\source_code\envi
ronment\include" - 
IC:\Users\abhishekj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include - 
IC:\Users\abhishekj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-    
IC:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program 
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows K
its\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tccmemcached_imp.c 
/Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\cmemcached_imp.obj
cmemcached_imp.c
c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'cmemcached_imp.c': No such 
file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have installed memcached on my machine and also able to do telnet please let help me through this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `pylibmc` depende on `python-libmemcached`. It [depends](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/install.html#requirements) on `libmemcached` which is [a different beast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667294/7976758).

Comment: but while installing libmemcached it does not find any relative package @phd

Comment: and after downloading that libmemcached package how should i install pylibmc?

Comment: `pip install pylibmc`. If libmemcached's files (headers and libraries) are in standard places `setup.py` should find them automatically.

Comment: where should i keep those files then?

Comment: Where your compiler looks for [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/335408/7976758) and [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13628917/7976758). Or pass them to `python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=… --library-dirs=…`; see `python setup.py build_ext --help`.

Comment: None of your option is working it is still me giving me same error